# Accessing __UTMZ cookie on first page view

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am using javascript to access the GA cookie __utmz when a user hits the page.  The problem I am having I am unable to get the information on the first page view.  The user must either refresh or navigate to a second page before I can see the information.

Is it possible to grab this info on first page view.  If there is specific parts of my code you would like to see please let me know.

Comment: Paste your entire HTML Page with all parts deleted but the code accessing the cookie and the loading of google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access __utmz after the callback from Google has completed.  As long as you're using a newer (~1.6+?) version of jQuery, the following *should* work:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

$.ajax({
  url: ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js',
  dataType: "script",
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    // Cookie reading code goes here
    console.log(readCookie("__utmz")); 
  }
});
```